# Struggling to interpret this SQL join syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join, inner-join

Two pretty similar queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_payments ep
INNER JOIN payments p ON ep.payment_id = p.id
    ON ep.employee_id = e.id
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN employee_payments ep ON ep.employee_id = e.id
INNER JOIN payments p ON ep.payment_id = p.id
```

But obviously crucially different syntax.

The way I learn these new syntax concepts best are to interpret them as plain English. So how could you describe what these are selecting?

I would expect that they'd produce the same results, but it feels to me like the `LEFT JOIN` in the second query acts as an `INNER JOIN` somehow - since a fraction of my results set are returned (i.e. the employees with payments).

If the first query 'says' **"give me all employees, along with any available employee_payments (that have already been joined with their payment record)"**- what does the second query say?

Comment: One of them has a syntax error, the other hasn't.

Comment: @jarlh Neither of them has a syntax error from what I can tell. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Both `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` need an `ON` clause. (`CROSS JOIN` is the only one without it.)

Comment: @jarlh - both have an `ON` clause though!?

Comment: @jarlh Both *have* an `ON` clause. `a LEFT JOIN (b INNER JOIN c ON cond) ON cond` is perfectly valid, and parentheses are not required.

Comment: @jarlh thought so too, but i've tested it on sql 2014 and the first query works.

Comment: Oops, seems like I was wrong here... Both of them are syntactically correct!

Comment: Both query will return same result.when Query Optimizer will make execution plan then it will auto detect that both query are same.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - that's not true, I'm afraid. Both massively different datasets are returned.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ, just now I wrote similar query,then Why both return me same result set.

Comment: Because all of your records satisfy the inner join. Remove all payments for one particular employee - they will now not appear in the results of query 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the first query 'says' "give me all employees, along with any available employee_payments (that have already been joined with their payment record)"- what does the second query say?

I suppose you might put it as "Take all employees along with any available employee_payments. Join this with the payment records."

The "Join this with the payment records" is what filters out employees that don't have any associated employee_payments records: the attempt to join with the payment records will fail.

> but it feels to me like the LEFT JOIN in the second query acts as an INNER JOIN somehow

It's not the LEFT JOIN that's doing the filtering, but it does indeed give the exact same result as if the LEFT JOIN had been an INNER JOIN.

Comment: Ahhh ok, nice! I like that explanation.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that what this means is that the `LEFT JOIN` effectively became an `INNER JOIN`, so leaving such a query with `LEFT JOIN` is just an invite to confuse future maintainers.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, the OP noticed that already, but it's indeed worth addressing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the logical order<sup>1</sup> in which joins happen, you need to look at the `ON` clauses. For each `ON` clause that you encounter, you pair it with the closest previous `JOIN` clause that hasn't already been processed. This means that you first query is:

```
INNER JOIN ep to p (producing, say, ep')
LEFT JOIN e to ep'
```

And your second query is:

```
LEFT JOIN e to ep (producing, say, e')
INNER JOIN e' to p
```

Since the conditions of the `INNER JOIN` rely upon columns present in `ep`, this is why the different join orders matter here.

---

<sup>1</sup>The logical join order determines the final shape of the result set. SQL Server is free to perform joins in any order it sees fit, but it must produce results consistent with the logical join order.

Comment: I goggled "order of join in sql server" and few article,it says that "which join will execute first depend upon query plan.. further the join which produces smallest result-set are join first and so on ".There are lot other factor also.
Example link  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3201/how-join-order-can-affect-the-query-plan/

Comment: @KumarHarsh - I mean the *logical* join order. That is, the order of join operations that SQL Server has to produce results consistent with. Physically, it's free to re-order joins as it sees fit.